# scp job in CRON does not run

Tags: shell, cron

I have this entry in my crontab (Proxmox 6 on Debian 10) :

```
* 3 * * * scp -i /home/myuser/.ssh/proxmox_user.id_rsa /nas-zfs/backup/dump/vzdump-lxc-*-$(/bin/date +"%Y_%m_%d")* proxmox_user@proxmox2:/mnt/ftp-backup/proxmox1/dump
```

When I run scp... from the shell, it works and does not prompt me for a password.

proxmox1 : server from which the files are copied
proxmox2 : server to which the files are copied
proxmox_user : a user on proxmox2 that can authenticate with a ssh key

I cannot find the cron logs yet in Proxmox (it differs from a standard debian) but the job obviously fails to run.  Any help is of course welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to roaima as replacing `$(/bin/date +"%Y_%m_%d")` with `$(/bin/date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d")` solved the problem.

Have a nice day.

Marc